# Error Message - Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'

Tags: sql-server, syntax-error, where-clause

I am running into an error when trying to execute the SQL statement below. Not sure if there is another reserved word or parentheses needed around WHERE, but I am running out of ideas.

I am getting the error --"Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'."

Can anyone help me figure out how to correct this error?

Thanks in advance!

```html
SELECT dbo.PURCHASING_DETAIL.ID
    ,dbo.SCA_SS_INVOICELINESALL.*
    ,dbo.SCA_SS_INVOICESALL.*
    ,dbo.PURCHASING_DETAIL.QUOTEDPRICE
    ,dbo.PURCHASING_DETAIL.GLACCT
    ,dbo.PURCHASING_DETAIL.[PO DATE]
FROM dbo.PURCHASING_DETAIL
INNER JOIN (
    (
        dbo.SCA_SS_INVOICELINESALL INNER JOIN dbo.SCA_SS_INVOICESALL ON dbo.SCA_SS_INVOICELINESALL.INVOICESALLID = dbo.SCA_SS_INVOICESALL.INVOICESALLID
        ) INNER JOIN dbo.PURCHASING_DETAIL ON (dbo.SCA_SS_INVOICELINESALL.SUPPARTNUM = dbo.PURCHASING_DETAIL.SUPPARTNUM)
        AND (dbo.SCA_SS_INVOICESALL.INVOICENUMBER = dbo.PURCHASING_DETAIL.INVOICENUM)
    )
INNER JOIN dbo.SCA_SS_LOCATION ON (dbo.SCA_SS_INVOICESALL.SHIPTOADDRID = dbo.SCA_SS_LOCATION.LOCATIONID)
    AND (dbo.PURCHASING_DETAIL.FACILITY = dbo.SCA_SS_LOCATION.FACILITYID)
WHERE (dbo.PURCHASING_DETAIL.[6DIGIT] = '50002')
    AND DATEDIFF(month, [PO DATE], GETDATE()) <= 12
```

Comment: It's the parenthesis around the INNER JOIN's thats the problem I think

Comment: Remove all the parenthesis (just leave the one for DATEDIFF() AND GETDATE()

Comment: @etsa Nope. Watch carefully `INNER JOIN
((dbo.SCA_SS_INVOICELINESALL
       INNER JOIN dbo.SCA_SS_INVOICESAL`

Comment: You have several issues-the `inner join dbo.SCA_SS_INVOICELINESALL` is written twice and the first time it does not have an `ON` clause. Format your query so that you can read it easily.

Comment: @Tyler How is the first inner-join joining? You have 4 inner joins, though only 3 `ON` clauses.

Comment: That's a problem I was running into as well. This is an older query that previously referenced a file name, so I'm trying to reformat.

Comment: You are also join Purchasing Detail after you start with that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also have some JOIN expressions that reference tables not in the join.  These should probably be in the WHERE clause.  It would work, but it's really hard to read.

I also agree that you should remove all the parentheses.

Also, as I mentioned in a comment, you have Purchasing_Detail twice.

Try this:

```
SELECT  dbo.PURCHASING_DETAIL.ID,
        dbo.SCA_SS_INVOICELINESALL.*,
        dbo.SCA_SS_INVOICESALL.*,
        dbo.PURCHASING_DETAIL.QUOTEDPRICE,
        dbo.PURCHASING_DETAIL.GLACCT,
        dbo.PURCHASING_DETAIL.[PO DATE]

FROM    dbo.SCA_SS_INVOICELINESALL

    INNER JOIN dbo.SCA_SS_INVOICESALL
        ON dbo.SCA_SS_INVOICELINESALL.INVOICESALLID = dbo.SCA_SS_INVOICESALL.INVOICESALLID

    INNER JOIN dbo.PURCHASING_DETAIL
        ON dbo.SCA_SS_INVOICELINESALL.SUPPARTNUM = dbo.PURCHASING_DETAIL.SUPPARTNUM 

    INNER JOIN dbo.SCA_SS_LOCATION
         ON (dbo.SCA_SS_INVOICESALL.SHIPTOADDRID = dbo.SCA_SS_LOCATION.LOCATIONID)

WHERE (dbo.PURCHASING_DETAIL.[6DIGIT] = '50002')
    AND (dbo.SCA_SS_INVOICESALL.INVOICENUMBER = dbo.PURCHASING_DETAIL.INVOICENUM)
    AND (dbo.PURCHASING_DETAIL.FACILITY = dbo.SCA_SS_LOCATION.FACILITYID)
    AND DATEDIFF(month,[PO DATE], GETDATE()) <= 12
```

Comment: This solved my (multiple) issues. Thank you for the reformatting as well. I am still learning how to structure SQL statements

Comment: Glad to help.  Good luck.

Comment: I would move AND (dbo.SCA_SS_INVOICESALL.INVOICENUMBER = dbo.PURCHASING_DETAIL.INVOICENUM)
    AND (dbo.PURCHASING_DETAIL.FACILITY = dbo.SCA_SS_LOCATION.FACILITYID)  from WHERE to JOIN clauses

Answer (score 0):

You have some unnecessary JOINs (like the duplicated `INNER JOIN dbo.PURCHASING_DETAIL`) and some useless parenthesis in your query. Try this:

```
SELECT  dbo.PURCHASING_DETAIL.ID,
        dbo.SCA_SS_INVOICELINESALL.*,
        dbo.SCA_SS_INVOICESALL.*,
        dbo.PURCHASING_DETAIL.QUOTEDPRICE,
        dbo.PURCHASING_DETAIL.GLACCT,
        dbo.PURCHASING_DETAIL.[PO DATE]
FROM    dbo.PURCHASING_DETAIL
JOIN    dbo.SCA_SS_INVOICELINESALL
    ON  dbo.SCA_SS_INVOICELINESALL.SUPPARTNUM = dbo.PURCHASING_DETAIL.SUPPARTNUM 
JOIN    dbo.SCA_SS_INVOICESALL      
    ON  dbo.SCA_SS_INVOICESALL.INVOICENUMBER = dbo.PURCHASING_DETAIL.INVOICENUM
JOIN    dbo.SCA_SS_LOCATION
    ON  dbo.SCA_SS_INVOICESALL.SHIPTOADDRID = dbo.SCA_SS_LOCATION.LOCATIONID AND
        dbo.PURCHASING_DETAIL.FACILITY = dbo.SCA_SS_LOCATION.FACILITYID
WHERE   dbo.PURCHASING_DETAIL.[6DIGIT] = '50002'
        AND DATEDIFF(month,[PO DATE], GETDATE()) <= 12
```

Comment: This would work, but I don't like the fact that that last "ON" statement still references two different tables linked to the joined table.

Comment: @JohnPasquet, that's not an issue, as sometimes you (really) need to make that kind of check.